# Unable to Import Module in Swift Xcode Project

Tags: swift, xcode, module, compiler-errors, importerror

I am facing an issue while attempting to import the CSVGenerator module into my Swift Xcode project without using any pods or frameworks. I've taken multiple steps to resolve the problem, including restarting Xcode and my computer, verifying file naming and target membership, and ensuring that the CSVGenerator.swift class is declared as public. However, despite my efforts, I am still encountering the error "No such module 'CSVGenerator'".

```
// Sample.swift
import Foundation
import CSVGenerator

class Sample {
    // ... Your Sample class implementation ...

    // Test function to verify CSVGenerator is imported and working
    func testCSVGenerator() {
        // Create an instance of CSVGenerator
        let csvGenerator = CSVGenerator()
        
        // Test a function or property from CSVGenerator
        let exampleCSVString = csvGenerator.generateCSVString(games: []) // Corrected the instance variable name
        print("Example CSV String: \(exampleCSVString)")
    }
}

//CSVGenerator.swift
import Foundation

public class CSVGenerator {
    // Rest of the CSVGenerator code...

    public static func generateCSVString(games: [GameData]) -> String {
        // Existing implementation...
        // Placeholder return statement
        return "CSV string will be generated here."
    }

    // Other methods...

}

struct GameData {
    // Stub implementation for demonstration purposes
    var puzzle: [[Int]]
    var solution: [[Int]]
}

// Test the CSVGenerator class
func testCSVGenerator() {
    let csvGenerator = CSVGenerator()
    
    // Test generating a CSV string
    let exampleCSVString = CSVGenerator.generateCSVString(games: [])
    print("Example CSV String: \(exampleCSVString)")
}

// Uncomment the line below to run the test
//testCSVGenerator()
```

Approaches Tried:

1. Ensured that **CSVGenerator.swift** exists in the same target and is correctly spelled.
2. Checked that **CSVGenerator** class is declared as public.
3. Verified that **CSVGenerator.swift** is included in the target membership.
4. Ensured that **CSVGenerator.swift** is included in the target
   membership.

The code should successfully import the CSVGenerator module without any errors, allowing me to create an instance of CSVGenerator and call its methods. I'm not using any frameworks.

Despite implementing the mentioned approaches, I am still encountering the error "No such module 'CSVGenerator'".

I would greatly appreciate any insights or assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If CSVGenerator is a class that is included in the same target then you don’t need to import anything. You import frameworks, swift packages, pods but never something included in the same module.

Comment: Thank you, Joakim, for the helpful clarification that importing a file within the same directory is unnecessary when both classes are in the same target.